# NaN Error in Javascript in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a calculator on dividing 2 variables in javascript. But I got an error like `NaN`. Please take a look at my code. I'm a beginner to javascript.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var  p_val, d_days, total_price
function calculate() {

    p_val =  parseInt(document.getElementById("purchased_price").value);
    d_days =  parseInt(document.getElementById("days"));
    total_price = parseInt(p_val/d_days);
    alert(total_price);
}


</script>
```

```html
       <div class="box-body">
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo validation_errors() ?></span>

                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Purchased Price </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="purchased_price" class="form-control" value="100000">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Number Of Days</label>
                                    <input type="text" id=days" class="form-control"  >
                                </div>
                            <form action="<?=base_url()?>" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Depreciation Value</label>
                                    <input type="text" id=result" class="form-control"  >
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="calculate">Calculate</button>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-body -->
                            <div class="box-footer">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" >Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="<?=base_url()?>location/location_list/" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" >Cancel</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Hello,
Im try to make calculator for divide 2 variable in javascript. But I got error like NaN Please look my code. I am beginner to javascript.

Comment: May be  `d_days =  parseInt(document.getElementById("days").value);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add .value to parse the value of d_days input like you did with p_val and not the whole object

```
d_days =  parseInt(document.getElementById("days").value);
```

Btw, when you get an error specifying that X var is NaN, it usually means that you tried to compute mathematically something that is not a number.

Comment: Now I got this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at calculate (1:632)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (1:592)"

Comment: @SanjayaPrasanna If your html is the same as what you've posted in your question, you're missing an opening quote on the days input field for **id**, which would explain why it's null. _id=days"_ - The same is true for _id=result"_